# Add captcha to last step of multi-step form

Tags: forms, captcha

I have a multi_step form which contains four steps. I want to add captcha to last step of the form.

Answer (score -1):

use this code in your `template.php`, you need to know what the ID of the last form is,

```
<?php
function MYTHEME_form_alter( &$form, &$form_state, $form_id ){
    if ($form_id == "YOUR_FORM_ID") {
            $form['my_captcha_element'] = array(
                '#type' => 'captcha',
                '#captcha_type' => 'Math',
            );
        }
}
?>
```

you can also replace the `Math` with `image`